# How to add dynamic hyperlink in Grid View according to certain condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my Website, I currently use a grid view which generates data from 3 tables namely status, Project_glance, Application_header. SQL Query returns 4 columns but in my grid-view i only shows 3 columns. The last column returns the Status_id of the project.The following is my .aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdProf" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"   AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanging="grdProf_PageIndexChanging">
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkView" Visible="true" Text="View" runat="server" >     </asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ApplicationID" HeaderText="ApplicantionID" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="PRGLProjectTitle" HeaderText="Project Title" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Project Status" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If the Status_id > 15 then only view hyperlink will visible otherwise the View hyperlink text will be changed to 'Edit' and a navigate URL will add to this hyperlink and another hyperlink 'Delete' will show to allow user to delete the project detail.

Please help me to find the correct solution for this..

Comment: Please don't post the same question on multiple sites. This was migrated and now needs merging. All work for other members of the community and moderators.

Answer (score 0):

First, add the delete Hyperlink to your ItemTemplate.

Then, to be able to access your Status_id field, you'll want to add that to your GridView's DataKeys.

Then, you can subscribe to your GridView's RowDataBound method, grab the Hyperlinks, check the status_id, and set the Hyperlinks' visibility accordingly.

```
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="status_id"

<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkView" Visible="true" Text="View" runat="server" >
     <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkDelete" Visible="false" Text="Delete" runat="server" >
</asp:HyperLink>

void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    HyperLink delHl = e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("hlnkDelete") as HyperLink;
    int statusId = (int)(sender as GridView).DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value;
    delHl.Visible = statusId <= 15; 
}
```

Comment: It shows **Index is out of range** error on this line `int statusid = (int)(sender as GridView).DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value;`.So what should I do?

Comment: @Nupur Did you add `DataKeyNames="status_id"` to your GridView definition

Comment: Yes I added DataKeyNames="status_id" in GridView definition.

Comment: Yes I added DataKeyNames="status_id" in GridView definition.It shows the following error"**Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index**

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
protected void grdProf_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

 if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {

   DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

   // Retrieve the status value for the current row. 
   string status = rowView["Status"].ToString();
   //Now you have the status 
   //get a reference to view hyperlink and hide it if that's the case
   Hyperlink hlnkView = e.Row.FindControl("hlnkView") as HyperLink;
   //example: 
   if(int.Parse(status)>15)
      hlnkView .Visible=false;//you are done

 }
}
```

As far as displaying an "edit" hyperlink, I would have an extra column next to the "view" column and hide or display this other hyperlink as necessary since in some cases you'll need one hyperlink column and in some cases you'll need two.