# How to add dynamic hyperlink in Grid View according to certain condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add dynamic hyperlink in Grid View according to certain condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410713/how-to-add-dynamic-hyperlink-in-grid-view-according-to-certain-condition)

In my Website, I currently use a grid view which generates data from 3 tables namely status, Project_glance, Application_header. SQL Query returns 4 columns but in my grid-view i only shows 3 columns. The last column returns the Status_id of the project.The following is my .aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdProf" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanging="grdProf_PageIndexChanging">
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkView" Visible="true" Text="View" runat="server" >   </asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ApplicationID" HeaderText="ApplicantionID" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="PRGLProjectTitle" HeaderText="Project Title" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Project Status" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If the **Status_id > 15** then only view hyperlink will visible otherwise the View hyperlink text will be 'Edit' and a navigate URL will add to this hyperlink and another hyperlink 'Delete' will show to allow user to delete the project.

Please help me to find the correct solution for this..